# How to create for-loop for Blackjack?

Tags: java, blackjack

Trying to create a blackjack game, and I'm having some trouble figuring out how to print out and array of cards.

So after the player has seen their first two cards, they can choose to either hit or stand.

When they choose to hit, I want it to print a random card from the array I've created and add the integer value of the card (using .rank to get int) to a variable to count their score.

Here I made a loop that filled two arrays with cards.

```
Card[] dealerDeck = new Card[21];
Card[] playerDeck = new Card[21];

for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
{
    dealerDeck[i] = deck.cards[i+11];
    playerDeck[i] = deck.cards[i+30];
}
```

How do I get it to print some random card from the array using a for-loop?

```
String temp;
int userChoice = 0;

while (score < 21 || userChoice != 1)
{   
    System.out.println("Do you want to HIT or STAND?");
    temp = scanner.nextLine();

    if (temp.contains("H") || temp.contains ("h"))
    {
        System.out.println(" ");  //This is for aesthetics 
        System.out.println("The dealer gave you a ");

        //you can use .printCard(); to print the card out
        // as King of Hearts, Four of Spades, etc.
    }
    else if (temp.contains("S") || temp.contains ("s"))
    {
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Your final score is "+score+".");
        userChoice++;
     }
}
```

Sorry if this a bit confusing, English is my first language.

I think I have it all in my head, I just need to get what's in my head into code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: print a random card from which array? from deck.cards?

Comment: by "print" do you mean print to the console using System.out.println()?

Comment: @mohsaied No, I mean printing using .printCard(); which is part of another method. I can post it if it would be helpful.

Comment: @mohsaied And yes, I do mean from deck.cards.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to change your arrays to an ArrayList as shown:

```
ArrayList<Card> dealerDeck = new ArrayList<Card>();
ArrayList<Card> playerDeck = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

This will enable you to remove cards from the Card arrays and modify them more easily. To pick a random card, use this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
void addRandomCard() {
  int randIndex = rand.nextInt(dealerDeck.size());
  dealerDeck.remove(randIndex);
  playerDeck.add(randIndex);
}
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Almost. I am very new to this and while this is great, it would be easier if you could do the same thing using the code I already have. I can provide more code as well if you may find helpful.

Comment: That code is very inefficient. First, create the Random object only once at program start. Then call nextInt(), and use that int to remove the card by index rather than fetching it and removing by value.  Or else shuffle the deck array and just deal with pop().

Comment: Thanks for the note Crocker. I updated the code to make it more efficient, but your idea of shuffling the deck would take a lot more processing than this. johndoefoe123, I would look up and learn ArrayList as it is extremely useful and used frequently in larger code (I use it ALL the time). It's pretty easy to learn and shouldn't take long. Post here if you have further issues.